# giving buttons in an array an own ID

Tags: javascript

I need help for a project I am doing for school. We need to make a booking system for a cinema. To generate the chairs I made an array but how do I give each button an own ID?

This is my code:

```
function chair(){    
    for( i = 1 ; i <= 10; i = i + 1 ){
        if (  i > 3 && i < 8 ){
            document.write("<button>button</button>");
        }else{
            document.write("<button>hi</button>");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could do this:

```
document.write("<button id=btn" + i + ">button</button>");
```

---

Side notes:

1. You're falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) — declare your `i` variable.
2. Normally barring a reason to do something else, in programming we start with `0` rather than `1`:

   ```
   for (i = 0; i < 10; i = i + 1)
   ```

   You don't have to, but that's the normal thing to do.
3. `i = i + 1` can be written `++i` ("increment `i`"):

   ```
   for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
   ```

   Again you don't have to, but that (or its cousin `i++`) would be much more common than `i = i + 1`.
4. `document.write` is fine for small class assignments and such, but just FWIW, you probably wouldn't want to use it in the real world. Use the [DOM](http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR) instead:

   ```
   var btn = document.createElement("button");
   btn.id = "btn" + i;
   document.body.appendChild(btn);
   ```

HTH, as you're learning...

Comment: Regarding point 3, JSLint will complain if you use `++i` or `i++`, so in JavaScript particularly, I think `i = i + 1` or `i += 1` is somewhat common.

Comment: @JLRishe: In my experience, it's very rare (esp. compared with `++i` or `i++`), I don't recall the last time I saw it. But yes, it's used.

Comment: @AmitJoki: *The Good Parts* is filled with all sorts of opinion-based, rather than fact-based, information. Crockford is intelligent and well-informed and it's smart to read him, but he's just as fallible as the rest of us.

Comment: I didn't say it's more common. I said it's somewhat common, and that JSLint enforces it. If you want your code to pass JSLint (without turning features off), don't use `++`. If you don't care about JSLint, that's fine too.

Comment: @JLRishe: You're right, I misread. But again: JSLint is just Crockford's opinions turned into a software program. (Something he's quite open about stating.) One of the many reasons to use JSHint instead is that Crockford is no more infallible than the rest of us.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder your turn... :) Will delete this comment sooon

Comment: @T.J.Crowder How do i put all of this in a div?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against `document.write`. You can do this

```
function chair() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var btn = document.createElement("button");
        btn.id = "btn" + i; // set the id
        btn.innerHTML = (i > 3 && i < 8) ? "Button" : "hi";
        document.body.appendChild(btn);
    }
}
```

P.S I've updated the answer to meet T.J.Crowder's suggestions in his side notes.

Comment: T.J. Crowder's suggestions aside, you should _never_ use `i = i++`. That doesn't even make sense (was it a typo?).

Answer (score 0):

```
function chair()
{
var ID = 0;
  for( i = 1 ; i <= 10; i = i + 1 )
  {
    if (  i > 3 && i < 8 ){
    document.write("<button id=btn"+id+">button</button>");
    } else{
    document.write("<button id=btn"+id+">hi</button>");
      }
  id++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var id=0;
for( i = 1 ; i <= 10; i = i + 1 ) 
{
    if (  i > 3 && i < 8 ) 
    {
        document.write("<button id="+id+">button</button>");
        id++;
    } 
    else 
    {
        document.write("<button id="+id+">hi</button>");
        id++;
    }
}
```